# Spring 4.0.0 basic authentication with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, apache, basic-authentication, resttemplate

I am currently working on integration of a third party application with our local reporting system. I would like to implement REST calls with basic authentication but facing issues in Spring 4.0.0. I have a simple solution what works nicely:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
final String plainCreds = "username:password";
final byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
final byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
final String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

final ResponseEntity<MyDto> response = restTemplate.exchange("myUrl", HttpMethod.GET, request, MyDto.class);
final MyDto dot = response.getBody();
```

but wanted to rewrite this to use **ClientHttpRequestFactory** in the following way:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(createSecureTransport("username", "password"));

private ClientHttpRequestFactory createSecureTransport(final String username, final String password) {
    final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    final UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, 9090, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), credentials);
    return new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
}
```

This code is not compiling as the **CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory** class not exists anymore in Spring 4.0.0. Do somebody know any alternative solution to this? I am quite new in this REST world therefore any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not check the Spring 4 APIs to see which classes implement the required interface, namely [`ClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html)?

As you'll see from the Javadoc, most likely you want [`HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html), which uses the client from Apache's HttpComponents, the successor to the old commons `HttpClient`.

Comment: Yeah i see your point now and almost fine, 
     my only issue now is that if i change the HttpClient to be import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; and create it as 
     final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
     i am not able to set the UsernamePasswordCredentials as there is no getState() on client. 
     I know that probably stupid question but could you please recommend something as seeing this really first time. Cheers!

Comment: To be honest, I don't know off-hand. However you'll find lots of other questions and answers on here on HttpClient 4 and how to authenticate with it.

Comment: Oki, thanks! I get this working just fighting with 401 Unathorized, but i think i am on right track. Thanks again for your answer helped to find the right direction. Cheers.

Answer (score 35):

I know that this is an old question, but I was looking for the answer to this myself. You need to add a RestTemplate interceptor when configuring the RestTemplate. An example below in annotation configuration:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(
            new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
            new StringHttpMessageConverter()
    ));
    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("client", "secret"));

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Javadoc for [BasicAuthorizationInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.html).

I was stuck on this for a good few hours. Maybe it will help somebody out in the near future.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! No need to manually add http auth headers etc.

Comment: Late to the party, but you need to add a converter for the media type you are returning. If you're using JSON/XML (e.g. a web service) you need to using an appropriate one, e.g.  new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()

Comment: i think its supports since spring 4.3 release.

Answer (score 19):

From http://www.baeldung.com/2012/04/16/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring-3-1/ **with HttpClient 4.3 edits**:

Both Spring 3.0 and 3.1 and now 4.x have very good support for the **Apache HTTP libraries**:

1. **Spring 3.0**, the `CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory` integrated with the now **end of lifed HttpClient 3.x**
2. **Spring 3.1** introduced support for the **current HttpClient 4.x** via `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` (support added in the [JIRA SPR-6180](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6180))
3. **Spring 4.0** introduced **async support** via the `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory`

Let’s start setting things up with HttpClient 4 and Spring 4.

The `RestTemplate` will require an HTTP request factory – a factory that supports **Basic Authentication** – so far, so good. However, using the existing `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` directly will prove to be difficult, as the architecture of `RestTemplate` was designed [without good support](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8367) for `HttpContext` – an instrumental piece of the puzzle. And so we’ll need to subclass `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and override the `createHttpContext` method: ([taken from soluvas-framework on GitHub](https://github.com/soluvas/soluvas-framework/blob/a67444a6852f81cec2fb23e2f7b8b32e7f5ebea2/commons/src/main/java/org/soluvas/commons/util/AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java))

```
package org.soluvas.commons.util;

import java.net.URI;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.AuthCache;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

/**
 * From http://www.baeldung.com/2012/04/16/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring-3-1/
 * 
 * <p>And with that, everything is in place – the {@link RestTemplate} will now be able to support the Basic Authentication scheme; a simple usage pattern would be:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * final AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
 *                  httpClient, host, userName, password);
 * final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
 * </pre>
 *   
 * And the request:
 *
 * <pre>
 * restTemplate.get("http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest-template/api/foos/1", Foo.class);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @author anton
 */
public class AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory extends
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {

    protected HttpHost host;
    @Nullable
    protected String userName;
    @Nullable
    protected String password;

    public AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpHost host) {
        this(host, null, null);
    }

    public AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpHost host, @Nullable String userName, @Nullable String password) {
        super();
        this.host = host;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient httpClient, HttpHost host) {
        this(httpClient, host, null, null);
    }

    public AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient httpClient, HttpHost host, 
            @Nullable String userName, @Nullable String password) {
        super(httpClient);
        this.host = host;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
       // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(host, basicAuth);

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        HttpClientContext localcontext = HttpClientContext.create();
        localcontext.setAuthCache(authCache);

        if (userName != null) {
            BasicCredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(host), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));
            localcontext.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
        }
        return localcontext;        
    }

}
```

It is here – in the creation of the `HttpContext` – that the basic authentication support is built in. As you can see, doing preemptive **Basic Authentication with HttpClient 4.x** is *[a bit of a burden](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#d4e1023)*: the authentication info is cached and the process of *setting up this authentication cache is very manual and unintuitive*.

And with that, everything is in place – the `RestTemplate` will now be able to support the **Basic Authentication** scheme; a simple usage pattern would be:

```
final AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
    new AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClient, host, userName, password);
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

And the request:

```
restTemplate.get(
    "http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest-template/api/foos/1",
    Foo.class);
```

For an in depth discussion on how to secure the REST Service itself, [check out this article](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/11/20/basic-and-digest-authentication-for-a-restful-service-with-spring-security-3-1/).

Comment: @ Anton Kurniawan What is httpClient parameter in AuthHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Answer (score 7):

Since Spring 4.3.1 there is a simplier way using [`BasicAuthorizationInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.html), which is also independent of underlying http client used in `RestTemplate`.

The example that uses [`RestTemplateBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html) from [spring-boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) to add `BasicAuthorizationInterceptor` to `RestTemplate`:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate myRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .rootUri("http://my.cool.domain/api/")
                .basicAuthorization("login", "password")
                .build();
    }

}
```

This way **any** request sent using `myRestTemplate` bean instance will include given basic authorization header. So be careful to not use the same `RestTemplate` bean instance to send requests to foreign domains. The `rootUri` is partially protects from this, but you can always pass the absolute URL when making the request using `RestTemplate` instance, so be careful!

If you are not using `spring-boot`, you can also manually add this interceptor to your `RestTemplate` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38945615/758991) answer.

Comment: Almost missed this relatively new option of `BasicAuthorizationInterceptor`, thanks!
@djxak: Maybe its worth mentioning that `RestTemplateBuilder` is Spring Boot but, although the main point of your answer remains, of course, valid.

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer simple over complex, then just set the header

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString("myuser:mypass".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    HttpEntity<SomeBody> myRequest = new HttpEntity<>(mybody, headers);
    restTemplate.postForEntity(someUrl, myRequest, null);
```

I'm sure there's some other Base64-library out there if the encoding that ships with the JDK is too verbose for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution to set basic authentication for customized rest template.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHost proxy =null;
    RequestConfig config=null;
    String credentials = this.env.getProperty("uname") + ":" + this.env.getProperty("pwd");
    String encodedAuthorization = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());

    Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    headers.add(header);
    // if we need proxy
    if(Boolean.valueOf(env.getProperty("proxyFlag"))){
        proxy = new HttpHost(this.env.getProperty("proxyHost"), Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("proxyPort")), "http");
        config= RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
    }else{
        config= RequestConfig.custom().build();
    }


    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);

    return restTemplate;
```